# Restrict video download

Tags: apache, download, html5-video

I want to block users to download video from apache/tomcat. I am using videoJS which streams video content. However it does allow users to download the video once the link to the video is accessed through browser. How can I restrict that?

Video streaming API is getting partial content (206) in its response. Usually download is only GET 200 response. Is there anyway in which we can restrict 206 response and allow 200 for a request from Apache?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved restricting download of videos by denying requests without referrer. I added referrer against a download url. If there is a referrer then download will be allowed by Apache else not.

Note - Couldn't restrict based on full or partial content.